# List counter with foldLeft

Tags: scala

I'm trying to do a simple counter of list elements and get something like List((a, 1), (b, 2)). But he compiler produces cryptic error messages about "following methods with _". I don't understands what's the problem...

```
  def counter(acc: List[(Char, Int)], c: Char): List[(Char, Int)] = 
      acc match {
        case Nil => List((c, 1))
        case (x, n) :: xs => if (c == x) (x, n+1) :: xs else (c, 1) :: (x, n) :: xs
      }

  chars.sorted.foldLeft(List[(Char, Int)])(counter)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in:

```
chars.sorted.foldLeft(List[(Char, Int)])(counter)
```

instead you should do:

```
chars.sorted.foldLeft(List[(Char, Int)]())(counter)
```

or

```
chars.sorted.foldLeft(List.empty[(Char, Int)])(counter)
```

Comment: Good catch! That fixed it :)